# Difference between Printk() and Printf() in Linux

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am a new user to Linux OS and am currently learning my way in it. I was studying about *OS Debugging* and related topics and as a basic debugging tool it is recomended to print out certain information regarding the state of the System.

This task can be accomplished by the mentioned functions `printf()` and also `printk()`, and have found that the "k" stands for kernel, and is some sort of "primitive" form of print function. Also that `printf()` is given by the C library rather than the kernel one (not completely sure of the meaning of this).

I was wondering if there is other advantage for using either of them other than the obvious one (which is to use `printk()` in earlier stages of the booting given that `printf()` is not yet avialable). Can one obtain the same information when using the two of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printk()` is a kernel level function, which has the ability to print out to different **loglevels** as defined in `<linux/kernel.h>`.

`printf()` will always print to a file descriptor - `STD_OUT`

> The major difference between `printk()` and `printf()` is the capability of the former to specify a loglevel. The kernel uses the loglevel to decide whether to print the message to the console. The kernel displays all messages with a loglevel below a specified value on the console.

[More Information Here](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3)

Comment: Link is dead. 404.

Answer (score 4):

`printf()` is a function in the [C Standard Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)

You are correct that you would want to use `printk()` if you did not yet have access to the C libraries yet. `printk()` gives you `printf()` functionality where you would not have it otherwise.

A good comparison of the two can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160818090942/http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3)

Edit note - [replaced dead link](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3) with static archive version

Comment: The second link is dead. 404.